# Telerik rad linear gauge is not rendering in pdf

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik rad linear gauge control in my asp.net page that works as expected in the browser. But it does not work in pdf.
PDF converter uses HTML string as source for the PDF. I am using the `base.Render(htmlTextWriter)` in an overridden `Render` method to get the html and print it.
But the resulting HTML does not have the HTML which is rendered in the browser. All I can see is an input control with some value in it.

Comment: The RadGuage renders SVG and not an image. The PDF doesn't know what to do with that so it can't be rendered. If you search for 'svg to pdf' you will find a lot of possible solutions, but none of them very ideal.